# Which side of the MOSFET's gate signal should be longer? Microcontroller to MOSFET driver or MOSFET driver to MOSFET gate

Tags: noise, inverter, mosfet-driver

I need to drive MOSFETs for a 3 phase 3 level inverter circuit. I have thought of two methods to design the circuit. I want to know which of the two methods will work the best in terms of noise immunity, rise and fall time of PWM, and other problems that might play here.

Following are the parameters:

- 20 KHz to 40 KHz switching frequency
- 3.3V PWM from microcontroller
- 12V PWM MOSFET driver output
- 3 phase AC inverter output

The main difference the two methods have is that method 1 has two connectors with 3.3V PWM on long wires of length 0.5m to 1m while the second method has one connector and 12V PWM on long wires with the same length.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you care about emissions interference with USB? acoustic step effects from high Q and L/RC resonance, losses and added complexity of suppression or matching source impedances to cable and losses.  None of the Answers have focused on specs

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That's because there is no specification of cable type nor the logic levels of the  MCU, & gate driver. A buffer/driver could be a line driver w/ impedance match & twisted pair,  or simple CMOS buffer & ribbon cable, It would require some more detailed view.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič That's my point. no answer is valid or correct without specs.

Comment: Let me be perfectly clear. Both methods work better if you match source impedance with compromises if you do not.  Method 1 is lower power with less energy being transferred over a longer distance, but NO ANSWER IS ACCEPTABLE UNTIL YOU DEFINE ALL YOUR SPECS, which is a question you must learn to define.  The options are simple with match driver impedances, but your awareness to thermal, acoustic , EMI issues and stepper resonance. Must be defined. Technically NEITHER OF THESE 2 CHOICES ARE BEST. Been there done that.  Got it?

Comment: Personally my choice is to use the best for the NEMA steppers with FOC drivers. https://us.nanotec.com/fileadmin/_processed_/f/5/csm_OpenvsClosed-Loop-en_2e2ee3e451.jpg

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Agree that it is possible to run the gate drive via a cable, too, but it is more involving because dI/dt is much higher than for the logic signal. Likewise one could also run the MOSFET output through the cable. Again more dI/dt.. Marko and me provide the likely answer given the general nature of the question. Everything about motors in your comments is hypothetical and has no substantiation in the question.

Comment: @tobalt I have successfully run well over 1m on all versions 1,2 and 3, with longest distance between power FET and motor..  no one addressed the issues of skew, deadtime, nor consequences of tradeoffs. But the best  reason is the lowest power one on the longest cable if you design to balance EMI with CM Z controlled design.  Or perhaps as my last design 30m cable on 3ph VFM BLDC 100W motor with longest cable on AC power and DC controls. Option 5. **When you answer myopic questions, you give them bad vision.**

Answer (score 3):

Always bring the gate driver as close as possible to the MOSFET *and* minimize the gate drive current loop.

The digital signal being sent to the gate driver is less critical. Good layout practice helps here, too, of course. So best is to use a good return current concept, e.g. microstrip and properly terminate it if you have a strong drive controller that is capable of fast rise times.

If you have to pass that signal through a cable, put a ground conductor alongside with it in the same cable.

Answer (score 2):

The 1st Method, of course. The gate driver has to be as close as possible to the MOSFET gate, the trace inductance plays a very important role, here.

The MCUs output could be enough or maybe not, for a such long cable it could be also good to have a high speed buffer/driver.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was already said, even if you get your "Method 2" device working, having a 1m long cables carrying 0-20V signals with microsecond-long edges will be a HUGE challenge to get FCC (or your local equivalent) certification for.